# Varnish client.identity -- how to split load more evenly?

Tags: load-balancing, varnish

I have two Varnish servers, in a middle-tier between an F5 load balancer and two application servers (Apache httpd). I want Varnish to split the load more-or-less evenly between the two Apache servers. Here's the important bits of the configuration I'm using:

```
backend prod1 {
  .host = "172.16.1.1";
  .port = "80";
}

backend prod2 {
  .host = "172.16.2.1";
  .port = "80";
}

director wpprod client {
  { .backend = "prod1"; .weight = 1; }
  { .backend = "prod2"; .weight = 1; }
}

sub vcl_recv {
  set client.identity = req.http.user-agent;
  set req.backend = wpprod;
}
```

The intent is to take a header that shouldn't change during a session, but should be semi-random (the client's User-Agent: header), and use it to split the load between the two back-end servers.

Unfortunately, in practice, the load is being split about 70-30, with one backend getting roughly twice as much traffic as the other.

I've also tried using the X-Forwarded-For: header that my F5s are adding as the client.identity, but had the same problem.

I could just tweak the weights a bit, to try to even out the load, but that's not really scalable, or feasible with more than a few servers.

Any suggestions on headers I can use that will result in a more even split of traffic?

Comment: So, this ultimately turned out not to be a Varnish problem at all. Elsewhere in our network, a runaway search engine/spider was hammering these servers. Since it was about 40% of all of our traffic, and since every request it sent had the same User-Agent:, fixing that problem restored the roughly 50-50 balance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Varnish 3.x and also assuming you need some kind of stickiness here (otherwise you could a random or round-robin director), you could populate `client.identity` with `client.ip`, or, even better, you could generate / use your own cookie to assign each client to a group:

```
...

sub vcl_recv {
    cookie.parse(req.http.Cookie);

    unset req.http.X-Group;
    if (cookie.get("group")) {
        set client.identity = cookie.get("group");
    } else {
        set req.http.X-Group = std.random(1, 1000);
        set client.identity = req.http.X-Group;
    }

    set req.backend = wpprod;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (req.http.X-Group) {
        header.append(
            resp.http.Set-Cookie,
            "group=" + req.http.X-Group + "; domain=.example.com; path=/; expires=" + cookie.format_rfc1123(now, 365d));
    }
}
```

Comment: client.ip won't work, because the Varnish servers are behind a load balancer. (Thus, all requests appear to come from the same IP.) And I tried using X-Forwarded-For: but had the same problem (a roughly 2:1 split between Varnish servers).

Comment: The "add your own cookie" idea certainly has merit, but it's more code, thus more things that could go haywire, more things I have to document, et cetera. If there's a better "native" way to split the load, I think it would be preferable. That said, I'm definitely going to implement something like this in my test environment, to see if it splits traffic more evenly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have good enough reputation to comment, this is quite old topic plus v3 is even older and I should not answer like this, but Google offers this and comment about `client.ip`os not accurate.

Of course `client.ip` works behind a proxy, sort of.

A proxy must setup a header for the IP of that client, like in Nginx:

`proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;`

That must convert to useful string to use instead of client.ip:

`std.ip(req.http.X-Real-IP, "0.0.0.0"));` where 0.0.0.0 is just fallback.

Using cookie for that is quite strange choice in Varnish.

Comment: As I'd noted in one of my comments on this, I had the same basic problem even when using the pre-existing "X-Forwarded-For" header (which was added by an F5 ADC). Ultimately, the problem in this case was that an irrationally large percentage of traffic was coming from a single source, which when there are only two back-ends, will inevitably lead to an imbalance.